# CSS make active navigation bar arrow

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to design my navigation bar for my website like the image above (Credits to StackExchange UX) for a small school project. But I'm not sure how to make the arrow for the active link.

My header:

```
<header>
    <img src="logo.png" height="125px" width="250px" style="margin-left: 15%;" />
    <div class="myNav">
        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>        
</header>
```

It looks a little something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:

[image]

After adding in the arrow my button seems to be expanded like so...

```
.myNav li a {
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 14px 16px 55px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: navy;
}

.myNav li a.active {
    background: transparent url('youarehere.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

I've added a bottom padding of 55px as shown above, which caused the button to be bigger. How do i shift only the arrow to the bottom without causing the button to expand?

Comment: You can get html and css of image above by right click choose inspect.

Comment: It's an Image, make a triangular image of small size and add to the active bar link.

Comment: If you look at the ux css for the active URL you'll see: transparent url('img/bg-nav-current.png?v=79f8dcf50ed7') no-repeat center bottom. The arrow is an image, you could technically grab it by saving it from the above link.

Comment: @Dandy, thanks! I didnt know it was that simple.

Comment: @Dandy, I am having a small issue over here. My navigations seem to be too big after I've added in the arrow image. Please look at my edited question...

Comment: What's the image size after downloading? Maybe that's causing it? You're using a % in your nav height. Try amending that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on exactly how closely you want to mirror the StackExchange UX header. Assuming you want to keep the same logo, and don't want to have an 'Ask Question' button, you could use something like the following:

```
<style>
.myNav {
    background-color: #2363a0;
}
.myNav li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.myNav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

That will set your background colour to match StackExchange UX's, along with changing the colour of your links. If you want to adjust the height of the header to be shorter like StackExchange UX's, you need to adjust the height of the logo.

EDIT:

As @Dandy pointed out, for the arrow, you need:

```
.myNav li a.active {
    background: transparent url('youarehere.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

The additional padding error you're facing is unfortunately not possible to correct with pure CSS. The problem is that you're adding padding to the link itself `.myNav li a {}`, rather than the visual button `.myNav li {}`. You're working out which link is active with `.myNav li a.active`, which is fine for adding the image, but unfortunately CSS has no ability to access the parent selector. That means you can never manipulate the correct element with pure CSS.

The way StackExchange UX solves this problem is with jQuery. Assuming you have access to jQuery, what you would want to do is:

1) Work out which link is currently displayed by grabbing it from the URL (with GET), depending on the structure of your site:

```
var page = window.location.pathname; // JavaScript
var page = $(location).attr('pathname'); // jQuery
```

2) Strip the first character:

```
var page = page.substring(1);
```

3) Do a calculation based on a match with the variable and the `<li>` text:

```
if (page.indexOf('courses') >=0 ) {
    $(".myNav ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("youarehere");
}
else if (page.indexOf('about') >=0 ) {
   $(".myNav ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass("youarehere");
}
etc.
```

4) Modify your code so that the triangle gets added to `.youarehere{}` instead:

```
.youarehere {
    padding: 14px 16px 55px;
    background: transparent url('youarehere.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

If you don't have access to JavaScript or jQuery, then unfortunately you'll need to either live with larger clickable areas, or remove that triangle. Of course, you could always simply add the class to the corresponding links in the raw HTML, but I'd assume that you'd want to use the same header code throughout the site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, my question was misunderstood due to poor explanation, sorry! I am asking about how to make that arrow on the li:active

Comment: Thanks, looks understandable however I'm stuck on the substring part.

`file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AceTraining/index.html`

`if (page == 'index') { // do code here }`

Am I doing it right?

Comment: using `if (page.indexOf('index') >=0 )` worked for me. Could you please update your code so I can mark you as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Done :) Glad everything worked for you in the end :)